# save state of uidatepicker popover which is called in two different view controllers and differentiate them

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, uidatepicker, viewdidload

I am able to popup a uidatepicker in a uipopover and send data back to the VC that pops it. I am essentially having two such VC's(StartdateVC and endDateVC) which popup the uidatepicker. I have to save the last date and start the uidatepicker with it when it is relaunched. So my code is in viewDidLoad of popover is,

```
if (myLastDate == nil) {
    [self.mydatePicker setDate:[NSDate date] animated:NO];
} else {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateStyle : NSDateFormatterLongStyle];

    [self.mydatePicker setDate:[formatter dateFromString:myLastDate] animated:NO];

[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

where I saved the myLastDate in NSUserDefaults and retrieved it here. I want to be able to differentiate between which VC has launched the popup and so be able to launch the uidatepicker with that corresponding last date. Any idea or tips is much appreciated. :)

EDIT:
In each of the VC's , I have this method:

```
- (IBAction)calendarbutton:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIView *anchor = sender;
    selectDatePopover *selectDatePopoverinstance =
    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"selectDatePopover"];
    // selectDatePopover.delegate = self;
    _popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:selectDatePopoverinstance];
    [_popover presentPopoverFromRect:anchor.frame inView:anchor.superview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    selectDatePopoverinstance.delegate = self;
    _popover.delegate =self;
```

}

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are launching a popover with a `UIDatePicker` from two different view controllers. Rather than the popover needing to know which `UIViewController` launched it, I suggest adding a property to the popover controller that contains the date to edit. In the `prepareForSegue` method, set the date property and delegate. Once the user is done, make a delegate call back to the parent VC with the new date.

Comment: But I do not use a prepareForSegue here .. @bobnoble

Comment: The same approach applies - add a date property to the popover controller, and when instantiating the popover controller, set the date property as appropriate, and use a delegate method to pass the new date to the parent controller. The parent controller then saves the new date in user defaults.

Comment: @bobnoble am sorry for asking this..but am new to ios..could you tell me in detail how does the VC send data to uipopover..??